# No effect on mysql database table by sending Arduino sensors data using python

Tags: python, mysql, arduino

I am trying to upload Arduino sensors data(DHT11, BMP180, Rain sensor) to MySQL server using python. But There is no effect on table in mysql server.
here is python code

```
import serial
import MySQLdb
import time
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "", database = "climate predictive analysis") or die ("could not connect to database")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
device = 'COM4'
try:
  print ("Trying...", device)
  arduino = serial.Serial(port = device, baudrate = 9600)
except:
  print ("Failed to connect on", device)    

while True:
    try:
      time.sleep(2)
      data = arduino.readline()
      print (data)
      pieces = data.split(" ")
      try:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO sensors_data (Rain, Temperature, Humidity, Pressure) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3]))
        mydb.commit() #commit the insert
        mycursor.close()  #close the cursor
      except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print ("failed to insert data")
##      finally:
##        cursor.close()  #close just incase it failed
    except:
      print ("Failed to get data from Arduino!")
```

sensors data is in this form

```
Rain Temp Hum Pres
0 31 60 985
0 31 60 985
0 31 60 985
0 31 60 985
0 31 61 985
1 31 61 985
0 31 61 985
0 31 61 985
0 31 61 985
```

python output
[This is output from python. In one line it is displaying the out in correct from but at other line it is saying that Failed to get data from Arduino. I don't know why?? Its output should in this form e.g (0 31 60 980)
What are **b** at beginning and **\r\n** at the end of output??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7gyh.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `'b'` at the beginning means that it is a byte array - rather than a string.
The `\r\n` are the characters to indicate the end of the line.

The arduino encodes and sends the strings in ASCII - where each byte is used to hold a single character. You need to convert this into a python unicode string (where more than one byte can represent a single character) before calling string operations.

It's failing on the `data.split()` call

Try changing your code to:

```
data = arduino.readline()
data = data.decode('ascii')
```

and it should get to the mysql code.

Comment: thanks sir it worked
I also used ```data.strip()``` method to remove  \r\n  from output